# Python script not accepting import function

Tags: pi-3, python, python-2.x

I've been writing a simple python script, and I import the GPIO library, and the time library. I have the following code.

`print()'Importing GPIO library' 
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
print()"Importing time library"
import time`

Yet I get this error message: `./RUNME.py: 2: ./RUNME.py: import: not found
./RUNME.py: 4: ./RUNME.py: import: not found`

I run the program with sudo, and I have version 2.7.13 of python.

What causes these errors, and what can I do to rectify them? Thanks!

Comment: Though that is not the problem, why put the string literals behind the ()?

Comment: Because whenever it string is inside the (), it gives me this message:

Comment: ./boop.py: 1: ./boop.py: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")

Comment: Though the answer down there is probably right... I'll check it out in a few minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't told the system that you want to run a Python script.  It probably assumes the script is a bash shell script.

You have a number of choices.

1. use the form `python RUNME.py`
2. add a `shebang` as the first line of your RUNME.py script.  I use `#!/usr/bin/env python`

For choice 2 to work you need to ensure the script is executable with

`chmod +x RUNME.py`